# How to solve this recurrence relation using substitution method

Tags: recurrence-relation

Can anyone explain to me how to demonstrate that,

$$T (n, d) ≤ T (n − 1, d) + O(d) + d/n (O(dn) + T (n − 1, d − 1))$$

is solved by

$$T (n, d) ≤ bnd!$$
for some constant $b$ using the substitution method?

I have done this but I don't know if it is correct:

- $T (n-1, d) ≤ b(n-1)d!$
- $O(d) ≤ bd$
- $d/n (O(dn) + T (n − 1, d − 1)) ≤ d/n (bnd + b(n-1)d(n-1)!)$

Comment: Your question contains a complete answer. I'm afraid we typically don't check answers. That's your TA's job.

Comment: Probably I didn't explain myself clearly. The exercises ask to demonstrate it inductively using the substitution method, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You didn't give the initial conditions, I mean value for T(0,d) for example or even T(0,1).... as a first thought I could get rid of the long division term as <= O(d). Then reach by substitution      T(n, d) <= T(0,n) + O(nd)